# Trying to run a Hello World Program from a tutorial, but the dialog box does not show

Tags: javascript

This is the file I am trying to run, but all it does is open the web page with the page title, it doesn't run the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html lang=”EN” dir=”ltr” xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/
xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=»content-type» content=»text/xml;
charset=utf-8» />
<title>HelloWorld.html</title>
<script type = «text/javascript»>
//<![CDATA[
// Hello, world!
alert(«Hello, World!»);
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried running on aptana and notepad, neither show the dialog box. I feel like I am forgetting a small yet significantly important part?

Answer (score 5):

Your quotes are a combination of angled quotes (« and ») and smart quotes (“ and ”). You need "regular" quotes, `"`, in both HTML and JavaScript. If your keyboard is automatically configured to do that replacement somehow, try using single quotes instead, or just swapping keyboard layouts for coding.

Comment: Not only that, but these double arrow things are in there.  Weird.

Comment: @Brad: Yep - angled quotes. They're used in French, for example. But thanks, I missed the smart quotes.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were referring to the left quote and right quote. in his doctype declaration.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, i missed some, thank you for the help! It runs fine now, and I also learned what angled quotes are!

Comment: @user1877731: You missed one (or a few) :) Can you post the updated file?

Comment: Yep, i missed a couple of the angled quotes in the meta line. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose single `' '` or double `" "` instead of `«` `»`.

Here is the corrected codes,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/
xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HelloWorld.html</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// Hello, world!
alert("Hello, World!");
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```